# Problems with web service, Axis2 and Rampart

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, xmlbeans, rampart

I'm new with the Web services and I have a problem obtaining the java files from a WSDL.

The devs of the servers gave me this information:

I have to generate the source with a xmlbeans binding using Axis2 and Rampart. The requests must be signed with a trusted certificate (I have one) and add a Timestamp.

That said, I downloaded the lastest versions of Axis2 and Rampart and executed the next command line without getting errors:

wsdl2java -d xmlbeans -uri https://juntadeandalucia.e-factura.net/puef/services/SSPPWebServiceProxyService?wsdl -o .\src\

I don't have a clue about how to configure Rampart (just copied the modules in repository/modules, inside Axis2 directory) and I don't know if it varies the result neither. The case is that, following the Apache web examples, I can't use the java source generated as is.

For example, to use the consultarFactura method I would need to write a source like this, following the Apache web examples:

> SSPPWebServiceProxyServiceStub webservice = new
>   SSPPWebServiceProxyServiceStub(url); ConsultarFacturaDocument doc =
>   ConsultarFacturaDocument.Factory.newInstance();
>   doc.setNumeroRegistro(numeroRegistro); return
>   webservice.consultarFactura(doc); //Return the response

But setNumeroRegistro() its not a method of ConsultarFacturaDocument (witch is an interface), its a method of another interface called ConsultarFactura defined inside the first one.

wsdl2java gave me a wrong or incomplete code?
I have to do something more before generating the code?
Can I use another framework to generate a more clean code? (I tried cxf, but wsdl2java gave me errors, using the xmlbeans binding or not).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

(Sorry for my bad english)